# Jquery Ajax doesn't send authorization header

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, basic-authentication

I try to make basic authentication with Jquery Ajax. I add authorization header to ajax request like this.

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "authorization": "basic 123456",
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://example.com/Auth.asmx/Authorization',
    data: null,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data, status) {
            console.log("Success");
            console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xmlRequest) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(xmlRequest);
    }
});
```

Then in ASP.Net web service I try get this header.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public void Authorization(string callback)
{
   string headers = GetRequestHeaders();
}

public string GetRequestHeaders()
{
    HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    if (ctx == null || ctx.Request == null || ctx.Request.Headers == null)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
    string headers = string.Empty;
    foreach (string header in ctx.Request.Headers.AllKeys)
    {
        string[] values = ctx.Request.Headers.GetValues(header);
        headers += string.Format("{0}: {1}", header, string.Join(",", values));
    }

    return headers;
}
```

When I print to headers I can't see authorization header

> Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Accept: */*
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>   Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
>   Host: example.com
>   Referer: http://localhost:9200/test.html
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
>   (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36

Why i can't see authorization header and how can i get this value?

> P.S. I use Jquery 2.2.3 in client side

I tried something different. I created Node JS server in my local than I send it same request to it. Authorization header still can't be show.

**I used an application "Postman" to created and send a request.** I add authorization header then send to my servers (both ASP.Net and Node JS). **I saw authorization header in requests from this application.**

For ASP.Net the output is

> Cache-Control: no-cache
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> **Authorization: Basic 12345**
>
> Host: 192.168.1.100
>
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.17.1
>
> Postman-Token: 5911bb3a-ea8a-4f81-8579-7e6aed3ced61

Then I took Jquery AJAX output from Postman application for creating this request.

```
  var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://192.168.1.107:1800",
  "method": "GET",
  "headers": {
    "Authorization": "Basic 12345",
    "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Postman-Token": "5911bb3a-ea8a-4f81-8579-7e6aed3ced61,3455808c-4a4f-4108-b819-f061b5a8e37e",
    "Host": "192.168.1.100",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

I changed my Ajax settings like this.

```
 $.ajax({
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "http://192.168.1.107:1800",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
          "Authorization": "Basic 12345",
          "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1",
          "Accept": "*/*",
          "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
          "Postman-Token": "5911bb3a-ea8a-4f81-8579-7e6aed3ced61,3455808c-4a4f-4108-b819-f061b5a8e37e",
          "Host": "192.168.1.100",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "cache-control": "no-cache"
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
                console.log("Success");
                console.log(data);
                callback("Authorization OK");
        },
        error: function (xmlRequest) {
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(xmlRequest);
            callback("Authorization Error");
        }
    });
```

When I send same request to my servers I couldn't see authorization header again.

Headers for my requests

> "host":"192.168.1.107:1800",
>
> "connection":"keep-alive",
>
> "pragma":"no-cache", "cache-control":"no-cache",
>
> "access-control-request-method":"GET",
>
> "origin":"http://localhost:9200",
>
> "user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36",
>
> "access-control-request-headers":"authorization,cache-control,postman-token",
>
> "accept":"*/*",
>
> "referer":"http://localhost:9200/main.html",
>
> "accept-encoding":"gzip, deflate",
>
> "accept-language":"tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7"

Answer (score 1):

Try this bro:

**JS Code (AJAX)**

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Hello 123456');
                },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: 'http://example.com/Auth.asmx/Authorization',
    data: "{'callback':'test'}",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function (data, status) {
        console.log("Success");
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (xmlRequest) {
        console.log("Error");
        console.log(xmlRequest);
    }
});
```

and you can read the value with:

**C# Code**

```
string auth = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"];
```

**NOTE:** If this does not work try to configure the cross origin request in your version of IIS, you can do it from the `Web.config` or from the IIS administration panel depending on the version: https://enable-cors.org/server_iis7.html

Comment: it doesn't work for me. In the web service it gives me an exception (System.NullReferenceException). It couldn't find "Authorization" header.

Comment: I see that in AJAX you have `data: null` when you really wait for the `string callback` parameter in the `Authorization method`, does the request come to ASMX? Where does the exception throw?

Comment: Hi Julian, authorization header never came to server. So  HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Authorization"] throw an exception. I tried something and updated my question. Can you suggest somehing for new situation?

Comment: i update my answer bro, try with the config in the iis server or the ajax code updated using beforeSend